# Strange Output - Ruby on Rails&MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new in Ruby on Rails, I am coding a heroku app to combine images and display it.

But my code output some strange things......I don't know what is it.

Here's my code:

```
<%=     

first_image  = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/summon.png")
second_image = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/(1).png")

result = first_image.composite(second_image) do |c|
    c.compose "Over"
    c.geometry "+20+20" 
end
result.write "output.png"
result << "output.png"

%>
```

Output:

```
#<MiniMagick::Image:0x007f22b8096640>
```

Edit: The output changes when I open the page every time.

Update:

It works in rails console. But doesn't work on Heroku.
I NEED it works on Heroku.

Comment: And you've confirmed that the code doesn't write the image to the file?

Comment: Yes. I searched all the app's folder, didn't see any "output.png".

Comment: Have you tried running the code outside of an ERB template?

Comment: Yes. I made controller do the action and then made view show the output. But error comes, it said:"Output.png is not found."

Comment: Can you try running the code from `rails c` and edit the output of that into the question?

Comment: Okay, it works. But after I push it to heroku, it doesn't work.

Comment: Writing to files will not always work on heroku, see [this help center article](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)

Comment: Got it. Is there any ways to write images on Heroku? Do I have to upload images to AWS?

Comment: Those images I need are temporary, and I guess Heroku can save it for a while. That's all I need. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're alright with the images getting cleared out at random.